# How to remove copyright block form page using xml in magneto2

Tags: magento-2.0

I want to remove the form footer using XML in magneto2.

I am trying to use the following XML:

```
<hello_index_index>
  <reference name="root">
   <remove name="block.name" />
  </reference>
</hello_index_index>
```

This is not working.

Comment: Typing in your title into a well known search engine got me this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80425/remove-block-from-layout-in-magento-2

Comment: Migrate to http://magento.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create your XML file at the following location `view/frontend/hello_index_index.xml` as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="empty" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
   <!--this is use for remove copyright--->
   <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true"/>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried with this: in your layout XML file on following location

> view/frontend/hello_index_index.xml

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
<update handle="empty"/>
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">        
    <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true"/>    
</referenceContainer>
```